# Excel Find and Replace regexp

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a whole list of entries in two columns say ColA as

```
dn: uid=HM_SERVICE1,cn=users,dc=somedomain,dc=main,dc=org
objectclass: inetorgperson
objectclass: top
objectclass: person
objectclass: organizationalPerson
sn: HM - SERVICE1
cn: HM_SERVICE1
userpassword: xxxx
uid: HM_SERVICE1
```

and Columns B has a value of say `HM_JOSHUASERVICE`

What I am trying to achieve is replace in column A, wherever `HM_SERVICE1` exists with the new value in Column B so my end result woudl be

```
dn: uid=HM_JOSHUASERVICE,cn=users,dc=somedomain,dc=main,dc=org
objectclass: inetorgperson
objectclass: top
objectclass: person
objectclass: organizationalPerson
sn: HM - JOSHUASERVICE
cn: HM_JOSHUASERVICE
userpassword: xxxx
uid: HM_JOSHUASERVICE
```

I heard that this can be easily done in excel , can someone please hel pme with this?

Comment: In A, is the multi-line text from dn: to uid in a single cell or a line per cell?

Comment: the multi-line text is in a single cell

Comment: Can't you just =SUBSTITUTE(A1,"HM_SERVICE1",B1) in C1?

Comment: LOL, yeah that does the job too, will check more and let you know. One Question, When I check the output it is now in quotes, can I remove them?

Comment: Whats in quotes? it should not add anything else

Comment: Sorry ignore the quotes.

Comment: the problem of using substitute is that it assumes I know the value of HM_SERVICE1, this I do not know. That value can be got from ColA uid =<value name> which in the example is HM_SERVICE1

Comment: Try =SUBSTITUTE(A1,MID(A1,SEARCH("uid=",A1,1)+4,SEARCH(",",A1,1)-SEARCH("uid=",A1,1)-4),B1)

Comment: @Alex K , I owe you one. Let me check this a bit more. Thank you for your time and patience

Comment: @Alex K  shift all this to an answer, thats what it is!

Comment: @Alex K, works like a charm, will accept this as the answer if you add it in the section. Cant accept your answer as the right one here( I think)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C1 you should be able to use;

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,MID(A1,SEARCH("uid=",A1,1)+4,SEARCH(",",A1,1)-SEARCH("uid=",A1,1)-4),B1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know RegEx I found a good article that quickly tells you how to configure you're environment so that you can use them in Excel. [It's here.](http://lispy.wordpress.com/2008/10/17/using-regex-functions-in-excel/) Hope that helps.